# How to get value of TouchSpin inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get the value of a Bootstrap TouchSpin element inside of a table? I'm currently getting nothing as I don't believe it is finding the element.

Creation of the touchspin and inserting into table

```
var table = document.getElementById("createOrderTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
row.id = 'row' + rowCount;

// TouchSpin element
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
var touchSpinID = 'touchspin' + rowCount;
cell1.innerHTML = "<input id='" + touchSpinID +"' type='text' value='1'  name='" + touchSpinID +"'>";
cell1.id = 'cell' + touchSpinID;

//Init TouchSpin
$("input[name='" + touchSpinID +"']").TouchSpin({
verticalbuttons: true,
min: 0,
max: 100000000,
});
```

Iterating through the table and getting the value of the Touchspin, neither method below works.

```
var table = document.getElementById("createOrderTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var productArray = [];

for(i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){
    var touchspinID = 'touchspin' + i;
    var touchspinValue = 0;        
    cellID = 'cell' + touchspinID;

    $(cellID).find(touchspinID).each(function(){
        touchspinValue = this.val();
        console.log(touchspinValue);
    });

    $("#createOrderTable tr").each(function () {
        $('td', this).each(function () {
            var value = $(this).find(touchspinID).val();
            console.log(value);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: What does your html look like? Would you be able to show an example snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I believe the issue lies with `touchspinID` and `cellID` in that they're both missing the '#' to indicate that you're looking for elements with those specific `id`s.

Changing these two lines from:

```
var touchspinID = 'touchspin' + i;
cellID = 'cell' + touchspinID;
```

to:

```
var touchspinID = '#touchspin' + i;
cellID = '#cell' + touchspinID;
```

should fix your issue. Also, you don't need to use `.each` after the call to `.find` as the cell will only ever have one "touchspin" element and `id`s must always be unique:

```
var touchspinValue = $(cellID).find(touchspinID).val();
console.log(touchspinValue);
```

If the above doesn't solve your issue, include the table html in your question.